# Universal document viewer in browser - without server side conversion

Tags: javascript

I want to embed a document viewer in my webpage, which should support all microsoft office formats, pdf, images, etc.

I don't want file conversion to happen on server side and then send it back to html viewer.

Is there a way to instantly view the file with original format directly in browser? Or is there a way to convert files to browser supported formats on fly in frontend (using Javascript) and show it instantly? Is there any product that does it now?

Comment: try using google docs, it supports all microsoft docs.

Comment: Universal? "images, etc"? Can't wait to see answers to this - on the doc side alone JS rendering all of `.epub`, `.azw` and `.prc` files next to `.odt`, `.pub`, `.tex` and the odd `.pdb` or `.wp7` files would be amazing.. Did you google this? Why don't you restrict permitted upload formats to `.pdf`, `.jpg` and `.png`?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search shows there are a few javascript libraries out there that can deal with MS Office docs, e.g. [DOCX.js](https://github.com/stephen-hardy/DOCX.js), although they may not cover all your use cases.